# how to skip the title of a theorem?

Tags: amsthm, box

I'm having problems with latex: I have a snippet that opens the theorem environment directly to me as in the code I published. That's when I am in "çç1" (this is a symbol I wrote to help you find where you should see in the code, it isn't helpful for the code, just to help you see where to look) and pass directly into "çç2" the compilation starts giving me numerous problems about extensions.
Apparently then I am forced to give a name to my theorem, and then necessarily write something in "çç1" (if you leave it blank, if you do not write anything between the square brackets, the code will not go).

I would like a code in which, when I leave the square brackets blank after the `\begin{Theorem}[]`, the code that should come out is simply `Theorem 1` (or whatever number the theorem is).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\newcommand\contra{\scalebox{1.1}{$\lightning$}}
% correct
\definecolor{correct}{HTML}{009900}
\newcommand\correct[2]{\ensuremath{\:}{\color{red}{#1}}\ensuremath{\to }{\color{correct}{#2}}\ensuremath{\:}}
\newcommand\green[1]{{\color{correct}{#1}}}
% theorems
\makeatother
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{skipabove=1em,skipbelow=0em}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries\sffamily\color{RawSienna!70!black}, bodyfont=\normalfont,
    mdframed={
        linewidth=2pt,
        rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false,
        linecolor=RawSienna, backgroundcolor=RawSienna!5,
    }
]{thmredbox}

\declaretheorem[style=thmredbox, name=Theorem]{Teorema}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{ciao}
ciao

\begin{Teorema}[çç1]\label{teo: ciao}
çç2
\end{Teorema}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "çç".  But is there a reason you can't leave out the `[]` entirely?

Comment: As @Teepeemm says, if you don't want an attribution to the theorem, just type in `\begin{Teorema}` without following brackets.

Comment: Yes I know, but I was asking if there is a way to improve my code in a way that if I leave the [] (with nothing written in it), my code doesn't break. Also when I wrote çç, it was a symbol to help you find in what part of the code you should see)

Comment: Theorems have nothing tp do with `amsmath`.  You have loaded `amsthm` so that's probably what you mean.  Please fix the tags.

Answer (score 2):

Try this patch:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\thmt@parsetheoremargs
  {\def\thmt@optarg{##1}}
  {\def\thmt@optarg{##1}\let\thmt@shortoptarg=\thmt@optarg}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem]{Teorema}


\begin{document}
\begin{Teorema}
  body
\end{Teorema}

\begin{Teorema}[]
  body
\end{Teorema}

\begin{Teorema}[title]
  body
\end{Teorema}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you @muzimuzhi Z for the answer, I have read the "question-answer" of Francesco and I have tried it and he is right, it doesn't work in the colorbox. I republish his question:"I have read the answer of muzimuzhi Z, and it does the job, but I don't see why it doesn't work when I want to modify the theorem style, like if I want to put it in a box, for example in the code below it doesn't work (if you try to put the [] after the theorem}"

Comment: It is the loading of `hyperref` that matters. And I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hi, yeah, this solution works!!! thank you